# Moving existing MySQL database to server with different OS timezone

Tags: mysql, date, timezone

I developed an application locally (this is my first real commercial app) and the timestamps were set to the timezone that the O/S was using. When I put my application on a server which is hosted in a different timezone I didn't account for the fact that `NOW()` and `TIMESTAMP` would produce different dates.

After reading about my issue apparently the correct way to handle this is to store the dates/timestamps in UTC and convert them on the client code to the specified timezone needed. Unfortunately I had my application running for a long time and I have 1000's of entries which stamped to a specific timezone where I made a hacky fix by:

```
SET time_zone='-6:00'
```

Now I'm struggling with DST (because the MySQL server does not support the timezone name which I am using).

Should I try and convert all my code to translate UTC->Timezone and all of the database to UTC? Or should I just get the host to install the proper timezone name which handles DST?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you though I'd convert your code to using storing/retreiving all time values in UTC and then adjust the values in your database appropriately.

It's a PITA I know, but in the long run it'll likely be less headache.

Answer (score 1):

It might hurt NOW but proper conversion maintaining everything in UTC is the way to go. Unless your app only needs to run for a few more days. You will want to manage this before the U.S.A. switches to non-DST  time. maintaining the system in UTC will save a lot of time down the road. Good Luck.